# Getting a sorted distinct list from mySQL

Tags: mysql

### Goal

I'l like to get a list of unique FID's ordered by the the one which has most recently been changed. In this sample table it should return FIDs in the order of `150, 194, 122`

### Example Data

```
ID    FID    changeDate
----------------------------------------------
1     194    2010-04-01
2     122    2010-04-02
3     194    2010-04-03
4     150    2010-04-04
```

### My Attempt

I thought distinct and order by would do the trick. I initially tried:

```
SELECT distinct `FID` FROM `tblHistory` WHERE 1 ORDER BY changeDate desc
# Returns 150, 122, 194
```

using `GROUP BY` has the same result. I'm just barely a SQL amateur, and I'm a bit hung up.  What seems to be happening is the aggregating functions find the first occurrence of each and then perform the sort.

Is there a way I can get the result I want straight from mySQL or do I have to grab all the data and then sort it in the PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, been reading questions on the site since I asked this one, and came up with an answer that seems to work, although I hope perhaps someone else may shed light on a simpler way:

```
SELECT t1.FID, t1.CD
FROM (
  SELECT FID, max(changeDate) as CD
  FROM sorted
  GROUP BY FID
) as t1 
WHERE 1 
order by t1.CD desc
```

Seems to get the results I expect. I didn't know subqueries existed until a few minuets ago. I'm a real SQL newbie.

Comment: Not sure why WHERE 1 is required though.

Comment: it probably isn't, I just replaced the more complex where clause for the actual example / real table. Although I created the table in my question to test on.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT FID
FROM tblHistory
GROUP BY FID
ORDER BY MAX(changeDate) DESC;
```

Comment: strange, I got an error of `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

Comment: What's the data type of your FID. Maybe I can replicate the issue that way.

Comment: FID is an integer. I like yours much better then what I came up with, other then it not working.

Comment: Strange, I tested the query out on a table ID (int), FID (int) and changeDate(datetime).

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tbl A 
where changeDate = 
    (select max(changeDate) from tbl where tbl.fid = A.fid)
order by changeDate desc
```